# How do you "step into" with fdb.exe?

Tags: flash, debugging, fdb

exe now for debugging. The problem is I don't know how to do "step into" with that. There're two command for stepping, "step" and "next", but it all behaves similar to "step over" in a GUI debugger.

So is there any good way? Maybe I need to set a break point in the beginning of the function i'm going to step into, continue the execution and finally remove the break point?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are on Windows (by the .exe I'm assuming so) then give FlashDevelop a whirl. It gives a GUI to FDB and has a "step into" button. The debugger's source should you some insight if the program itself isn't practical.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/

Comment: i've being not checking this website for several weeks. thank you for this informative stuff.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=debugging_02.html

- `step` is "Step into"
- `next` is "Step over"

`step` works for me.