# How to debug external ActionScript file?

Tags: flash, debugging, actionscript

I have a flash file that include external ActionScript, I can use `trace` but what I want is to setup some break points to debug interactively.

Is it possible? And any other workaround if it is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by external ActionScript? Do you have the source of this "external AS"?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible, I would regard it as the normal case (having ActionScript in .as files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [fdb](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffb.html) from the command-line or with an IDE to set breakpoints and [step into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083629/how-do-you-step-into-with-fdb-exe) files based on line numbers or method names.